# How To Stop a Texture from Tiling in the BI

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I was texturing an eye for an Animatronic I'm modeling from Five Nights at Freddy's. His name a Balloon Boy, and when I put the eye texture on, it becomes smaller, and begins to tile all over the eye. I want to know how to stop this.

Comment: What render engine are you using?

Comment: Blender Render.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the texture 'Extension' type from 'Repeat' to 'Clip'. This option is in the 'Image Mapping' panel in the texture settings:

[image]